# How to import module by variable name and how to name said module

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to import a python script depending on a variable name. Say I pass this function the module path, I'd like it to import that module from the path I passed ***and*** give it a name. Example:

```
import some_module as sm
#Would import some_module
```

What I want is something like this

```
module_to_import = some_other_module
import module_to_import as mti
#Would import some_other_module
```

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense, was quite difficult to put into words.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html?highlight=importlib#importlib.import_module) you could do this:

```
from importlib import import_module
module_name = 'some_module'

mti = import_module(module_name)
```

meaning you could import the module from a string. in your case you might get that name from your other module using

```
module_name = some_other_module.__name__
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

What you probably are looking for is ability to dynamically import modules

```
module = __import__(module_name)
my_class = getattr(module, class_name)
instance = my_class()
```

You can read more about this and alternative solutions at [this link](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/31/advanced-python-how-to-dynamically-load-modules-or-classes/)